# Problems with setInterval function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, setinterval, repeat

I'm using the setInterval function in JavaScript but I get like one hundred reps per second from the console.log('NOW').
setTimeout also has the same effect.

Where is my mistake?
I want to call the function "function1" every 15 minutes.

JavaScript Code:

```
   function1() {
      console.log('NOW');
      .
      .
      .
      });
    },
    refreshData() {
      this.function1();
      setInterval(this.refreshData(), 900000);
    },
```

**Thanks in adavance!**

Answer (score 3):

you're invoking the function

```
setInterval(this.refreshData(), 900000);
```

rather than passing a reference to a function

```
setInterval(this.refreshData, 900000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function call like This:

```
    var self = this;
    refreshData() {
      this.function1();
      setInterval(function(){  self.refreshData() }, 900000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways:

In provided code you should use `setTimeout`, because you restart function manually:

```js
function function1() {
  console.log('NOW');
}

function refreshData() {
  this.function1();
  setTimeout(this.refreshData, 3000);
}

refreshData();
```

Or simply replace existing logic with `setInterval`, it should do all the job you've implemented manually:

```js
function function1() {
  console.log('NOW');
}

this.function1();
setInterval(this.function1, 3000);
```